# How do you make this little circle thingy?

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to make this circle between the "18 minutes ago" and the "Like". Is there html for this? Is it a styled period?

[image]

Comment: Did you look at it in Firebug?

Comment: I did. It wasn't very helpful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
&middot;
```

[Here's a full list of codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are unicode characters for bullets - i.e. it's likely to be just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Unicode character 'MIDDLE DOT' (U+00B7).